# Outtputing all member's information

Tags: members, custom-fields, zoo-visitor, member-details

I've built a system for Schools which has a teacher/student hierarchy based on a custom field, I want a teacher to be able to login and view which of their students has registered with the system.

It basically needs to check the current logged in users custom member field "School code" and output any people from member group 5 that match the same "School code".

I'd like to know if this is possible with 
{exp:member:custom_profile_data}

I only seem to be able to output the current users information, is it possible to output all user's information or do I need to use something like Zoo Visitor?

Thanks!

Comment: In your case I 'd suggest you to use Zoo Visitor which store member data in channel entry form. Also it would be better to use Relationship between School and Students. By doing so school as well as students info can be fetched easily.

Comment: Thanks Bhashkar, so is there no way to output members information from the base expressionengine install?

Comment: you can populate member's custom profile data with native tag of member module but what if you are relating teachers/students and schools. So using Zoo visitor seems me better. Please share if you other approach. I 'd be glad to share my thoughts.

Comment: We have a schools channel where an admin sets up a school, in this we set school_code. The admin also sets up the teacher account where the custom member field is populated with the same school_code. When a student registers they have to provide this code which then associates them with the school. Each peice of content can be related to one school or all schools (a relationship field to school channel). We then have an if else before each exp:entries tag to only output entries that are assigned to all schools or their specific school which is defined by their custom member field.

Comment: This is already setup, but the issue comes when we want to output students details to the teacher with the same School code, as I can't work out how to expose other member details with the default expressionengine tags, is it even possible?

Comment: "an if else before each exp:entries" - why do not use search:field="school_id|ALL" parameter?

Comment: I haven't come across the search:field param before, looks awesome though, so could I specify school_id|{member_code} OR school_id|0 OR school_id|1 ? I currently have: {if {member_school} == "{people_school}{people_school:school_code}{/people_school}" OR "{people_school}{people_school:school_code}{/people_school}" == "0" OR "{people_school}{people_school:school_code}{/people_school}" == ""}